# Can I determine whether the OS is run in a virtual machine in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, virtual-machine, vmware

Maybe this is a cross-system issue, and maybe not. But I am just working on Mac OS X, therefore I focus on Cocoa.

As my title described, can I detect whether my application is run in an virtual environment programmatically? (not only **vmware**, but also some other virtual environment like **Sandboxie** in Windows)

Comment: What is "Sandbox"? Are you talking about the Mac OS sandbox?

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: @Chuck I meant **Sandboxie** of Windows. Maybe there are similar software with this one. Just for a example.

Comment: @mipadi There may be some unexpected behaviors in simulated OS X system. We do not want them seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any native Cocoa API's to specifically ask if you are running in a virtual machine vs real hardware.

However, if you know the potential environments you are running under you should be able to use IOKit to query the hardware of the virtual machine.

Virtual Machines will have considerably different hardware than a real Mac so you should be able to detect a real Mac vs a VM based on hardware configuration.

I can not give you any direct code, however, there is a section on Apple's site that discusses accessing hardware with IOKit in general:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_IOKitLib_API/AH_IOKitLib_API.html

IOKit is an advanced subject so if you do not have a lot of experience with the lower-level APIs you may find it a bit confusing as compared to Cocoa.

Comment: I think the most probable virtual machine is VMWare, which has many crack and tutorial about simulating OS X all over Internet. But it simulate hardware perfectly, the only differences may be the model of hardware. Do you mean I should query them, and guess the VMWare environment by these hardware models?

Comment: The hardware it is simulating, however, is *not* standard Mac hardware. Actually, the devices it emulates have "VMWare" in their name, so you should be able to use IOKit to enumerate the hardware and check for VMWare specific devices.

Comment: Look in the hardware and search for "VMWare" information, am I right? BTW, I just check an simulated OS X's /dev directory, and found a device named "vmmemctl" which my macbook doesn't have. Do you think this a reliable way to check VMWare?

Comment: That could very well be a way to detect VMWare as it does look like that /dev/vmmemctl is specific to VMWare memory management. However, from what I have read on various sites, the user may not have this specific module installed, so it may not be a 100% reliable way to detect VMWare.

Comment: Thanks!!! However, It may take me some time to study the hardware configurations among different Mac devices...

Comment: You don't really need to worry about different Mac devices or their hardware configurations. If you are going to try IOKit, enumerate your virtual machine hardware and look for hardware with "VMWare" in the name, no real Mac will have hardware with "VMWare" in the name, ever, so that should be a reliable way to check. One place you may find easy to check right away is the video card, back when I used VMWare I remember the video card had a name that should be pretty detectable as it is not an nVidia or AMD card, so try that first. :)

Comment: I would not assume VMWare as Parallels and VirtualBox are also very popular. And they work just as well. All 3 have areas where they are not perfect, but VirtalBox is open source and you can check its docs to find out what it displays. And it's free so you can test it yourself. Devs for all three are reading the apple developer mailing lists also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can cross-compile [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) and make use of it.

Comment: It is not a C-project? I wanted to call the interface programmatically.

Comment: I got another solution [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9823/Detect-if-your-program-is-running-inside-a-Virtual). But I cannot compile them in Xcode...

Answer (score -1):

In addition to I/O Kit you could use C POSIX functions. Check the man pages.

Comment: What POSIX functions do you think of? *"Check the man pages"* is a quite general recommendation, that will probably not help here.

Comment: sysctl.h should get you going, but you may have to figure out different things by Virtual Machine or seek reference from the producers of those machines. Check the man pages is NOT a general recommendation when you've noted POSIX C functions. man pages include far more than what is in the C headers for those. The man pages are ESSENTIAL for POSIX C headers.